# Android googlemap on the emulator without map

Tags: android, google-maps

I have confused with the problem for many days.
    When I run it on the emulator 4.2.2 api 17, it shows that :The app won't run unless you update  Google Play service.

I have no idea what should do. My code are listed:

**Manifest:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.demogooglemap"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.demogooglemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!--  The following two permissions are not required to use      Google Maps Android API v2,but     are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.demogooglemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
 <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

     <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyB6ZyogESLYJrYzZJ2h0QTJyyPna8m3CCI" />
     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
         android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


    <activity
        android:name="com.example.demogooglemap.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>

 </manifest>
```

**xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>`
```

**avtivity:** `package com.example.demogooglemap`;

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
 import android.view.Menu;

 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

  }
```

also I have imported the google-play-services_lib.

Comment: do you have the updated google play services

Comment: I download it from the SDK Manager. How can I update it?

Comment: open the sdk manager and update your google play services

Comment: there is no update that I could choose. Could you please give me a detail?

Answer (score 0):

You handle Google Play Services incorrectly. You should (I'd say "must") check if it matches what linked lib requires and act acordingly (use own code instead of mine 26354):

```
int errorCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(mContext);
if( errorCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS ) {
    if( GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError( errorCode ) ) {
        Dialog errorDialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.
                    getErrorDialog(errorCode, this, 26354);
        if( errorDialog != null ) {
            errorDialog.show();
        } else {
               // open GooglePlayService app page in store:
               // https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms
    }
}
```

or open this link on your device: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms

Comment: How can I know my own code? and I dont have the "TDApplication"

Comment: Thanks, I have tried, but it stopped and the logcat shows that"java.lang.NullPointerException", I dont have the parameter"mContext".

Comment: Of course you do not have it, geeez! But you have the docs for `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()` so you can substitute it with right stuff. This is genereic **example** code not copy-and-paste-without-understanding stuff

Comment: I an sorry. I am just learning the program with android. Yhank you all the same.

Answer (score -1):

By going to SDK Manager update the Android api version to 19

Search in start button of windows,type `**SDK Manager**` you will get there you will see some update,Install that Updates

[SDK Manager](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html)

Comment: You mean install the Android 4.4?

Comment: the google play library should be in you workSpace/working Directory and even add the for you project add google play library...